# Is there any known way to manipulate other applications' UI elements in macOS?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Is there any means by which a macOS application can make changes to the UI of other applications that are running? Some examples of the kind of thing I'm talking about would be changing the text in a read-only text field, force-enabling a disabled button, or adding controls to a window, but in another application, and not one that was designed to support such interaction.

If you're wondering what my use case is, I'm simply interested in tinkering with software. I imagine I'd need to disable System Integrity Protection, and I'm fine with this. But is there an existing framework or API to do this, even a private one?

Answer (score 1):

There is no framework or API to do this, as it is obviously not welcomed by Apple in any way.

However, you will be able to do this with some efforts.
I would say, you will need to write a library, inject it in the target process context, and then search UI elements by some marks you should find out yourself for each app separately.
Once you got the element reference - you can change its properties.